# Not getting specific costs associated with allocation tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-billing

I am building a python dashboard so that my clients who I have applications hosted on AWS can pay the exact amount there project costs me. I am using the python sdk but I only get my accounts overall amounts from my queries.

I have been sure to add the tags to the projects (ex: elastic beanstalk) and activated the cost allocation tags but it has been to no avail.

```
cost_allocation_tag = 'Company'

client = boto3.client(
    'ce',
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
)

try:
    monthly = client.get_cost_and_usage(
            TimePeriod={
                'Start':end,
                'End':now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            },
            Granularity='MONTHLY',
            Metrics=[
            'BlendedCost',
            ],
            GroupBy=[
            {
                'Type': 'TAG',
                'Key': cost_allocation_tag
            },
            ]
        )
    monthly_cost = monthly['ResultsByTime'][0]['Groups'][0]['Metrics']['BlendedCost']['Amount']
except:
    pass
```

I should get costs only associated with the tags not the overall. I have read the documentation but I am not 100% on if I followed it correctly. Here is the link to the docs

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage

Answer (score 2):

You want to group by **'TAGS'** type and not 'TAG' as that is not a valid type.

Also, check that tag values for companies are set on resources for the given tag key. 
If this isn't so, the groups returned will include resources for all the companies together.